# Python classes, why should I return a copy of obj in getters?

Tags: python, class, getter

I understand that we use getter and setter to prevent users from directly modify class' data attributes. But why do we have to return a copy or immutable object in getter? Can a user mutate those variables if the returns are mutable?

```
    def get_encryption_dict(self):
        '''
        Used to safely access a copy self.encryption_dict outside of the class
        
        Returns: a COPY of self.encryption_dict
        '''
        return self.encryption_dict.copy()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: python does not enforce to return a copy in "getter" / property, it is just that your use case needs to return a copy

Comment: Short answer: Yes, if you return a mutable object the user can modify it. Not only that, even if you return a copy or immutable object, the user might still mutate the elements inside that object, e.g. the values of the dictionary (the keys should be immutable anyway).

Comment: please copy the code as text in question, not [pasted as image].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to be careful in python (as in other languages) as some objects are mutable. Most important and common cases are the collections types, like `list` or  `dict`.

For instance, if the code in your example were this one, then it would have returne the mutable reference to the dictionary!

```py
return self.encryption_dict   # WARNING, do not do that at home / in your own class code, mutable reference returned, oyu probably don't want it!

return self.some_other_internal_list  # same warning!
```

> But why do we have to return a copy or immutable object in getter? Can a user mutate those variables if the returns are mutable?

Yes! For instance, calling `.clear()` on the returned dict would clear the internal dictionary used by the object... ooops...

You can easily make a copy of the enumerable list or dictionary like in the code example: use `.copy()` to [get a (shallow) copy](https://thispointer.com/python-how-to-copy-a-dictionary-shallow-copy-vs-deep-copy/) of all the dictionary, `[:]` for a list.

```py
return self.encryption_dict.copy()   # much less risk here, the internal dictionary from the object can't be modified, it's a (shallow) copy returned.

return self.some_other_internal_list[:]   # Ok as well, the '[:]' actually creates a copy of a list.
```

As noticed in comments, be careful that if an object is mutable, you getting a proper copy of a list still expose **the reference to same object**, which can be unexpected. (That's why we call these "shallow" copies, in opposition with "deep" copies).

As a rule of thumb, thriving for immutability will protect you from subtle (or less subtle) bugs.

Comment: So what to do if the returned is list or dict? Should I use deepcopy? Or convert them to string?

Comment: using a shallow copy is a good first step. Creating deep copies may not be trivial at all. A good tradeoff would be to return a list or dictionary of _immutable objects_ indeed. But I suppose we'll need a more detailed example to decide.